# Test paths or methods of a class

Tags: unit-testing

When writing unit tests for a stateful object with many optional methods, do I define my units as the individual methods of the class or as particular paths that can be taken through the class? Or is my unit the entire class?

To illustrate, imagine a class that sends a single e-mail and has several methods like: `send, attachBinary, attachText, clearAttachments, addSender, addRecipient, addCC, setBody, setSubject`. Only a single call to addRecipient is strictly necessary for an email to be valid, but I can imagine any number of paths to take: adding attachments, removing previously attached files and adding new ones, changing the recipient, etc.

How should I go about writing tests for a class like this? If I'm testing paths, am I still writing unit tests despite this feeling more like integration testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### "Unit" or "Not Unit"

If all the "parts" really belong to the class, then your class is the unit, and as long as you're testing methods of this unit, that's, ahem, unit testing.

If you feel like your object has methods that need to be tested completely differently, maybe you class can be split in smaller "units", that you can test to.

#### Testing paths or methods

Some of those methods might be private, and can only be exercised by calling a few, "public" methods ; that's fine. Don't think one method needs to have a single corresponding tests.

This convention is dangerous, as it can imply you need one test per method:

```
@Test
private void testSendMail() {
   // Code for a test for mail with attachement

   // Code for another test for mail without attachement

   // Code for hundreds of other tests...
}
```

This one is probably healthier :

```
@Test
private void testMailsCanBeSentWithAttachement() {
}

@Test
private void testMailsCanBeSentWithMultipartAttachement() {
}

// etc...
```

Writing many tests to test a single method, with many different behavior, is usually fine, too. 
Although, if it adds overhead, testing the individual "smaller" methods is probably ok.

#### SPOILER : Private methods

You'll get to a point where the simplest things to do will be to call a "private" method in a test. As this point, changing the method to be public or protected become a [philosophy debate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-to-test-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or-inner-classes). My (personal) opinion is to go on with your life, extract or expose some protected methods, and test them.

#### "What's in a name ?" vs "Does size matter" ?

Finally, the difference between "unit" and "integration" test is a fine subject for debates in a bar ;  the more I write tests, the more I like separating tests by ["size"](http://googletesting.blogspot.fr/2010/12/test-sizes.html).